# Making the show page url at the site root after logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently, when a user logs in or signs up, they are redirected to /users/1, for example, as their show page.

I can't figure out what routes to use to redirect them to just the site root (example.com, for example, instead of example.com/users/1). The logged in site root would be the show page, the logged out site root would be the normal site home page.

I'm using devise, if it matters.

Current routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout',
                                      :password => 'password', :confirmation => 'verification',
                                      :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'signup',
                                      :sign_up => 'new' }

  devise_scope :user do
    get   'login',          to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get   'users/login',    to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get   'logout',         to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get   'signup',         to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    get   'password',       to: 'devise/passwords#new'
    match 'users/secret',   to: "devise/passwords#create",      via: :post
    match 'sessions/user',  to: 'devise/sessions#create',       via: :post
    match 'users/signup',   to: 'devise/registrations#create',  via: :post
    match 'users/signup',   to: 'devise/registrations#create',  via: :post
  end

  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  root 'site#index'
```

Updated Routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout',
                                      :password => 'password', :confirmation => 'verification',
                                      :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'signup',
                                      :sign_up => 'new' }

    get   'login' => 'users/login'

  devise_scope :user do
    get   'login',          to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get   'users/login',    to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get   'logout',         to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get   'signup',         to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    get   'password',       to: 'devise/passwords#new'
    match 'users/secret',   to: "devise/passwords#create",      via: :post
    match 'sessions/user',  to: 'devise/sessions#create',       via: :post
    match 'users/signup',   to: 'devise/registrations#create',  via: :post
    match 'users/signup',   to: 'devise/registrations#create',  via: :post
  end

  get '', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
  get 'edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'user/edit'

  #resources :users
  resources :sessions

  # Authenticated Users:
  authenticated :user do
    root to: "users#show", as: :authenticated_root
  end

  # Non-Authenticated Users
  root to: 'site#index'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `authenticated` and `unauthenticated` resources.

Like this:

```
authenticated :user do
 root to: "users#show", as: :authenticated_root, via: :get
end

unauthenticated do
  root 'site#index'
end
```

Then in your users controller you'll need to make sure to check for the devise helper `current_user` instead of the `id` because you aren't passing one.

like

```
if params[:id]
  @user = User.find params[:id]
else
  @user = current_user
end
```

If you don't want users to be able to access this route, its easier to manage in the controller.  Just modify the if statement, something like

```
if params[:id]
  if current_user
    @user = current_user
  else
    flash[:notice] = "This page is not available"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
else
  @user = current_user
end
```

Updated routes:

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout',
                                    :password => 'password', :confirmation => 'verification',
                                    :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'signup',
                                    :sign_up => 'new' }


get   'login' => 'users/login'

devise_scope :user do
  get   'login',          to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  get   'users/login',    to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  get   'logout',         to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  get   'signup',         to: 'devise/registrations#new'
  get   'password',       to: 'devise/passwords#new'
  match 'users/secret',   to: "devise/passwords#create",      via: :post
  match 'sessions/user',  to: 'devise/sessions#create',       via: :post
  match 'users/signup',   to: 'devise/registrations#create',  via: :post
  match 'users/signup',   to: 'devise/registrations#create',  via: :post
end 


#resources :users
resources :sessions

# Authenticated Users:
authenticated :user do
  root to: "users#show", as: :authenticated_root
end 

# Non-Authenticated Users
root to: 'site#index'

get '', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
get 'edit', to: 'users#edit' as: 'user'
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! However, with `<%= link_to "Profile", current_user %>`, the links shows up as `/users/1` still.

Comment: Yep ~ And if you use the if statement it should work for both cases when the `id` is sent and not sent.

Comment: I don't want the `/users/1` route to be available (actually, anywhere on the site). Should I post a new question for that?

Comment: Updated answer -- additionally if you use the devise helper for show to force authentication this will only be accessible by logged in users ever

Comment: It's still available with your updated answer. Also, what about routes like `/users/1/edit`, for example? Would an '/edit` path work in your example? Instead of using a method, wouldn't a custom route be better?

Comment: If you want a custom route, feel free -- edit is not affected by the answer above because the conditional is localized to the `show` action.  Edit will still work as normal, but you might modify the action so that only the current user or admin could edit their record.

Comment: I see...The path `/users/1` is still available, though. Any ideas?

Comment: You can change the routes from `resources :users` to `get 'users', to: 'users#show'` then the only user routes you'll have will be one for show and then the user devise routes (like edit user registration, create, etc)

Comment: Forgive me for dragging this out and not being clear. This is my my goal: when loggied in: example.com and no example.com/users/1 or example.com/users. Your latest suggestion prevents /users/1 but allows /users.

Comment: Change the route to `get '', to: 'users#show'`  -- Are you seeing how these routes work?  all the pieces?  That first argument can be anything you want it to be, even blank (as denoted by the quotes).

Comment: I see! Thanks so much for your time. Presumably, then, `get 'edit, to: 'users#edit` will direct to example.com/edit. Also, now, `<%= link_to "Profile", current_user %>` returns an error: `undefined method `user_path'` Is there a different helper to use in this instance?

Comment: aah, ok you need to make sure it's a named route, since you aren't using resources anymore.  So add and `as` like `get '', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'`

Comment: Getting this error now: `No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: post your current routes

Comment: I updated my answer - routing table is read in order so make sure you put them in the order that you need them to follow a set of rules.

Answer (score 2):

In your **routes.rb** *(change the destination `to:` to the pages you wish)*

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do

  ...

  # Authenticated Users:
  authenticated :user do
    root to: 'user#show', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  # Non-Authenticated Users
  root to: 'site#index'

end
```

Rails 4 Fix: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393#issuecomment-17298414

In **UserController.rb**: Make sure in your show method, that you use `current_user` instead of `params[:id]`.  You do this because typically whenever you call your show action you send it an `id`, however in this case, you're not going to be doing so.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if params[:id].present?
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    else
      @user = current_user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Getting an error: `Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' You may have defined two routes with the same name...`

Comment: Actually, now, that error is absent (before your update). I'm getting this error, however: `Couldn't find User without an ID`. The `show` def is: `def show @user = User.find(params[:id]) end`.

Comment: use `current_user` if `params[:id]` isn't present.  Typically when calling the show, you're sending an `id`, but because you're not, you need to specify to use the `current_user`